# Why does this LINQ throw "FormatException was unhandled"?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-list

I am trying to get a val using LINQ from a generic list like so:

```
private List<PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated> CombineSubsets(string unit)
{
    List<PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated> combinedSubsets = new List<PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated>();
    if (unit.Equals(CRAFTWORKS_SC))
    {
        foreach (PriceVarianceSubsetData pvsd in craftworksWeek1PVDSubsetList)
        {
            PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated pvda = new PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated
            {
                ShortName = pvsd.ShortName,
                ItemCode = pvsd.ItemCode,
                Description = pvsd.Description,
                Price1 = pvsd.Price,
                Price2 = GetPrice2(CRAFTWORKS_SC, pvsd.ShortName, pvsd.ItemCode)
            };
            pvda.Variance = "0.00";
            decimal price1 = Convert.ToDecimal(pvda.Price1);
            decimal price2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pvda.Price2);
            . . .
```

The key part (that is failing to do what I want it to) is the call to GetPrice2(). That method starts out:

```
private string GetPrice2(string _unit, string _shortname, string _itemcode)
{
    string price2 = "0.00";
    if (_unit.Equals(CRAFTWORKS_SC))
    {
        price2 = craftworksWeek2PVDSubsetList
            .Where(x => x.ShortName.Equals(_shortname))
            .Where(x => x.ItemCode.Equals(_itemcode))
            .Select(x => x.Price).ToString();
    }
    . . .
```

...when I step into the assignment to price2 there, the val that is assigned is:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Pivotal.PriceVarianceSubsetData,System.String]
```

?!?

The err msg given is:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value)
       at Pivotal.FormMain.CombineSubsets(String unit) in c:\Projects\PriceVariance\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 290
       at Pivotal.FormMain.GenerateAndSaveSpreadsheetFile() in c:\Projects\PriceVariance\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 154
       at Pivotal.FormMain.buttonRun_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\PriceVariance\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 137
. . .
```

So this line (290) fails:

```
List<PriceVarianceDataAmalgamated> pvdaCraftworks = CombineSubsets(CRAFTWORKS_SC);
```

...and more specifically this one (line 154):

```
decimal price2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pvda.Price2);
```

Apparently the bad code is this:

```
price2 = craftworksWeek2PVDSubsetList
    .Where(x => x.ShortName.Equals(_shortname))
    .Where(x => x.ItemCode.Equals(_itemcode))
    .Select(x => x.Price).ToString();
```

On stepping through it where it blows up, both "_shortname" and "_itemcode" have a valid value; it is entirely possible that there is no value to select, but I seem to be defending against that by assigning a default value to price2:

```
string price2 = "0.00";
```

price2 is returned at the end of the method - perhaps I should use a catch block and assign the fallback value there rather than from the git-go?

Comment: Try `.Select(x => x.Price).First().ToString();`

Comment: Your more specifically line is identical to the earlier

Comment: I agree with earlier, but use FirstOrDefault which won´t throw an exception, instead returning a null value for reference types and default value for value types. Might make it easier for you to find where the problem is.

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari If not having the item is a logical error, then `First` (which throws) might be better than `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I changed it to FirstOrDefault and it seems to work just dandy. Mikael, you can make that an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
.Select(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

which won´t throw an exception, instead returning a null value for reference types and default value for value types. Might make it easier for you to find where the problem is

Comment: The ".ToString()" appears to be redundant/moot. It works fine without it, and adding it makes it appear gray.

Comment: That is something new to me, but I guess there is some new features to LINQ. My guess is since you declare the variable "string price2 = "0.00";" as a string instead of var, somehow the query already knows what to convert it to. Thanks for that input, something I will have to look into.

Answer (score 1):

`price2` is declared as a `string` but your LINQ query is writen so that it can potentially return a list.

`FormatException` makes me think that you're probably getting multiple items back and trying to push that result into a single variable. Using `var` for local variables would help expose this issue.

AlexD suggested `.Select(x => x.Price).First().ToString()`. I think this will make sure you get only one result.

You may also want to think about `.Distinct()` to make sure your getting a single type of result. It wouldn't make much sense to select the first item without first making sure there are not multiple types of answers.